# NSNetService initWithDomain use local IP address?

Tags: ios, network-programming, streaming

I am writing an app that features image streaming between 2 iPhones.  I am using much of the sample code provided by Apple for creating network streams (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/SimpleNetworkStreams/Introduction/Intro.html).

My question is whether I need to pass the local IP address of the other iphone in the line below instead of "local":

```
self.netService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_x-SNSDownload._tcp." name:@"Test" port:port];
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

depends on the network setup. If your iphones share the same (local) network domain, "local" should be sufficient. If you are trying to reach the other phone globally then you would have to identify the domain in which the phone resides (e.g. the global IP address your inet provider provided you with)